# Unable to register endpoint for Websocket based Springboot Application. ERROR http://localhost:4200/greeting/info?t=1691450261423 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular, spring-boot, websocket

I have a backend created in springboot with Websockets. When I try to connect from Angular i get the following error:

```
websocket.service.ts:19        
        GET http://localhost:4200/greeting/info?t=1691450261423 404 (Not Found)
```

Websocket config code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/greeting")
                .setAllowedOriginPatterns("http://localhost:4200","*")
                .withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
                .enableSimpleBroker( "/topic/","/queue/");
    }
}
```

Websocket Controller

```
@Controller
public class WebSocketController {
    private final SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;

    public WebSocketController(SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate) {
        this.simpMessagingTemplate = simpMessagingTemplate;
    }

    @MessageMapping("/message")
    @SendTo("/topic/reply")
    public String processMessageFromClient(@Payload String message) throws Exception {
        String name = new Gson().fromJson(message, Map.class).get("name").toString();
        return name;
    }
```

It lives alongside regular rest api

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/messages")
public class MessageController {
    ...

    @GetMapping("/sentBy/{email}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAllSentMessages(@AuthenticationPrincipal OAuth2User user, @PathVariable("email") String email) {
        if (user == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("", HttpStatus.OK);
        }...redacted for brevity
}
```

Also have websecurity enabled using Auth0 OKTA as:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                        .requestMatchers("/", "/index.html", "*.ico", "*.css", "*.js", "/api/user","/greeting/*","/chat/*").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2Login(withDefaults())
                .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt(withDefaults()))
                .csrf((csrf) -> csrf
                        .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                        .csrfTokenRequestHandler(new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler()))
                .addFilterAfter(new CookieCsrfFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(new SpaWebFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Now when I try to connect to this websocket using the following Angular code:

```
connect() {
    console.log("Initialize WebSocket Connection");
    let ws = new SockJS("/greeting");
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(ws);
    const THAT = this;
    THAT.stompClient.connect({}, function () {
      THAT.stompClient.subscribe(THAT.topic, function (message: any) {
        console.log(message)
        THAT.showGreeting(message.body);
      });
    }, (error:Error) => {
      console.log("errorCallBack -> " + error)
      setTimeout(this.connect, 5000);
    });
  };
```

I get 404 (Not Found) error. Also note that I have a proxy configuration in angular:

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: ["/api", "/oauth2", "/login", "/greeting", "/chat"],
    target: "http://localhost:8080",
    secure: true,
    logLevel: "debug",
  },
];

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

I have tried updating the connect code

```
from:
let ws = new SockJS("/greeting");
TO
let ws = new SockJS("http://localhost:8080/greeting");
let ws = new SockJS("ws://localhost:8080/greeting");
```

None worked. Removal of any authentication code on a barebones project worked as intended.

Comment: You should pass auth token with your connect request.

Comment: @Raj Check the websecurity config, "/greeting/*" and "/chat/*" are allowed. Also if it was about auth toke, the error code would be 403 Unauthorized.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone looking for this solution. This is what resolved my issue.

My WebsecurityConfig had a SpaWebFilter() at the end.

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                        .requestMatchers("/", "/index.html", "*.ico", "*.css", "*.js", "/api/user").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2Login(withDefaults())
                .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt(withDefaults()))
                .csrf((csrf) -> csrf
                        .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                        .csrfTokenRequestHandler(new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler()))
                .addFilterAfter(new CookieCsrfFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(new SpaWebFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
```

So I configured the WebFilter as:

```
public class SpaWebFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    /**
     * Forwards any unmapped paths (except those containing a period) to the client {@code index.html}.
     */
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String path = request.getRequestURI();
        if (!path.startsWith("/api") &&
                !path.startsWith("/ws") &&
                !path.startsWith("/login") &&
                !path.startsWith("/oauth2") &&
                !path.contains(".") &&
                path.matches("/(.*)")) {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.html").forward(request, response);
            return;
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

I just added the websocket endpoint:

```
!path.startsWith("/ws") &&
```

And this is the final websocket config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws");
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
                .setAllowedOriginPatterns("*")
                .withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
                .enableSimpleBroker( "/topic");
    }
}
```